# How to stop websocket message queue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket

I am not sure what the correct name for this is, so I am calling it 'websocket message queue'.

I am using websockets in javascript and everything works as expected until my server restarts, or the internet connection is lost. Once the connection is restored, the browser (chrome) appears to be storing the messages that were not sent successfully during the closed connection. This creates a burst of old messages coming into my websocket server upon connection.

The only way I have found to get around this is by manually refreshing the browser page, which seems to clear out the queue of failed messages.

Is there a way to programmatically tell Javascript "If there is no connection, don't store the messages, just discard them"

I can see how in some cases you would want those failed messages, but in my case I do not.

My code is as follows:

```
function socketConnection(id, WS_URL) {
    let ws;

    ws = new WebSocket(WS_URL);
    function isOpen(ws) { return ws.readyState === ws.OPEN }

    ws.onopen = () => {
        console.log(`Connected to socket`);
        if (!isOpen(ws)) return; //ensures websocket is open before it sends.
        ws.send('ping');//Send ping on load to obtain values
        ws.send('online?'); //check for online status
    }

    ws.onmessage = (message) => {
        if (message.data.length>10)
        {
            var status = JSON.parse(message.data);
            console.log(status)
            if (status.lightStatusA == true)
            {   
                document.getElementById(id+"towerLight").src = spacesLocation+ 'towerLight_green.png';
                console.log('im green')
            }
            if (status.lightStatusB == true)
            {
                document.getElementById(id+"towerLight").src = spacesLocation+ 'towerLight_red.png';
            }
            if (status.lightStatusC == true)
            {
                document.getElementById(id+"towerLight").src = spacesLocation+ 'towerLight_amber.png';;
            }
            if (status.lightStatusA != true && status.lightStatusB != true && status.lightStatusC != true)
            {
                document.getElementById(id+"towerLight").src = spacesLocation+ 'towerLight_none.png';;
            }
            document.getElementById(id+"enviro").innerHTML = status.temp + 'C '+status.humid+'%';
        }

        if (message.data == "online")
        {
            online = Date.now()
        }
    }

    ws.onclose = () => {
        console.log('closed, reconnecting...')
        socketConnection(id, WS_URL)
    }
    
    ws.onerror = (e) => {
    console.log('error');
    console.log(e);
    }
}
```

My plan is to add a `location.reload();` to the `onclose` function, so that the page will just autorefresh to clear out this message queue. But I would much rather not refresh the page if there is a more proper way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

> A websocket is a protocol layer on top of a TCP socket. TCP is meant to be a reliable transport which means that when it has trouble sending data (but has not received any sort of notification that the socket has been closed by the other end), it hangs on to that data and retries. It will eventually give up and communicate back some error.

Quoting [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) from: [Websockets - does a custom queueing system make sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42303675/3022603)